# Why is the domain of the hyperbolic function $\sinh x$ is symmetric about the origin?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

My book asked me to prove that the function $\sinh x$ is odd, but in order to be odd I must be sure that the domain of it symmetric about the origin, how can I be sure from this?

Comment: The usual definition of $\sinh x$ is $$\sinh x=\frac{1}{2} (e^x-e^{-x})$$ Now use the definition of an odd function $f(x)=-f(-x)$ to prove that $\sinh x$ is odd

Comment: "My book asked me to prove that the function $\sinh x $ is odd" - there's no talk about domains here, you just need to prove it's odd according to the definition of an odd function

Comment: @YuriyS: Yes, there is a condition on the domain, but since the domain in this case is the whole real line, it is trivially satisfied.

Comment: @HansLundmark, thank you for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sinh x:=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2=\color{red}-\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}2=-\sinh(-x)=-f(-x)$$

Comment: My question is : why is the domain symmetric?

Comment: @hopefully Fair enough: what is **your definition** of "symmetric domain"?

Comment: Symmetric about the origin

Comment: @hopefully That doesn't say much to me...By definition, a function $\;g\;$ with a definition domain symmetric wrt the origin (meaning:a domain of the form $\;(-a,a)\;,\;\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ ) is odd if $\;g(-x)=-g(x)\;$ ...

Comment: Correct .... this is the condition that I want to be sure of

Comment: or shall I assume that the domain is symmetric ?

Comment: @hopefully...Well, read again **carefully** my answer...Do you know the exponential function $\;e^x\;$ ? Do you know it is defined **everywhere**?

Comment: yeah sorry ... all the time I was thinking about its range